# Expanding on a step in the calculation of ζ(f,χ,s) = Λ(s)

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

I'm trying to understand the derivation here:

[image]

Above, f is defined as a product of Schwartz-Bruhat functions which are their own Fourier transform.

I was hoping someone could spell out the second equality in the main calculation:

$$ʃ_{^{×}_{ℚ}} f(x) χ(x) |x|ˢ dˣ x=2 ʃ e^{-x_{∞}} {x^{s-1}}_{∞} {dx}_{∞} • Πₚ ʃ_{ℚ_{p}^{×}} 1_{ℤₚ} {|xₚ|^{s}}_{p} dˣxₚ$$

Comment: May I ask what the source is?

Comment: @A.Bailleul here's a link to the pdf. https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/sheth/tate/tateweek4.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that
$$f(x)|x|_{\mathbb{A}}^s=\prod_v f_v(x_v)|x_v|_v^s,$$
where the product is over the places of $\mathbb{Q}$, and the functions $f_v(x_v)$ are the local factors in the first display. Hence, by the definition of the integral over $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}^\times$,
$$\int_{\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}^\times}f(x)|x|_{\mathbb{A}}^s\,d^\times x=\prod_v\int_{\mathbb{Q}_v^\times}f_v(x_v)|x_v|_v^s.$$
This is the sought equation, because the local integral over $\mathbb{R}^\times$ is twice the integral over $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

**P.S.** The quoted source has at least 3 typos. See my comment under this post.

Comment: I still don't understand the Archimedean factor. How does the $e^{-2pix²}$ turn into a term with single degree polynomial in x? It seems like we take u(t) := x(log(t))

Comment: Oh, that's a change of variable $u=\pi x^2$. Note that $x_\infty^{s-1}$ should be $x_\infty^{s/2-1}$, so there is a typo in the second display. Note also that $du/u=2dx/x$, so in fact there should be no factor of $2$ in the second display (which is a second typo). A third typo is that the factor $\pi^{-s/2}$ is missing in the second display. At any rate, this calculation over $\mathbb{R}^\times$ is classical, and is part of the standard proof of the functional equation of $\zeta(s)$ due to Riemann.

Comment: du = 2πxdx, and dxˣ is dx/x for ℝ. And yet we still get s-1 above, as if this du is taken care of. I like that you removed this trivial character, that was confusing me a bit.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the source was just wrong.  Now, this author has three terms in the integral: "f(x)χ()||ˢ". I am used to two. Also χ was the trivial character but I kind of want to combine χ()||ˢ... my question is, "is this just a difference of characters χ : G⭢ ℂˣ vs. characters χ : G ⭢ S¹"

Comment: can |x|ˢ be understood as the missing (0,∞) component of a unitary character.

Comment: Trivial character means the constant 1 map. So you can omit that factor. I recommend that you learn these things from Goldfeld-Hundley's book (volume 1). It is precise and thorough.

Comment: And yes, if $\chi(x)$ is an idele class character, then so is $\chi(x)|x|_{\mathbb{A}}^s$. So one can work with $\chi(x)$ only, but of course the $|x|_{\mathbb{A}}^s$ factor is only unitary when $\Re(s)=0$. Another good source for this material is Weil's Basic Number Theory, or Tate's thesis which was reproduced in the 1965 book edited by Cassels and Fröhlich.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will read that one then.